# Role-based authorization with G Suite

Tags: oauth, google-apps, google-workspace

I have an internal web app for employees, which uses the OAuth 2.0 flow for authentication. That allows me to check the email address of the user authenticating, and check that they are in fact an employee.

I would like to be able to assign custom roles to users, for example "Support", and then be able to check during authentication what roles the user have, so my application can perform authorization accordingly. I'd like the roles to be manageable through the G Suite admin dashboard as much as possible.

Can someone point me in the right direction on how to implement this?